# how do I set up an SMS server?

Tags: java, php, c++, sms

Just like google as the number GOOGL (46645), I would like to also set up a server like this that will have the ability to receive text messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms) doesn't yet support shortcodes, you can be up and running accepting text messages using simple POST requests sent to your server very quickly. There are other similar services out there as well so look around and use the one you like the most.

[Full disclosure: I work for Twilio]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice tutorial showing [how to receive SMS using a PC](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToReceiveSMSUsingPC.asp) (or the [full SMS tutorial here](http://www.developershome.com/sms/)).

Remember that this is Telco territory, so make sure you have capital to grease their pockets.  And know that everything you do will be made as difficult as possible, further inhibited by proprietary protocols.